# Facebook NPE java.lang.Object com.facebook.inject.Lazy.get()

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have Facebook login it was working properly but some how I'm getting the following crash for some users. I'm not asking any extra permissions:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object com.facebook.inject.Lazy.get()' on a null object reference
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:485)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:429)
   at com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol.fetchAllAvailableProtocolVersionsForAppInfo(SourceFile:790)
   at com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol.access$000(SourceFile:49)
   at com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol$NativeAppInfo.getPackage(SourceFile:281)
   at com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol$NativeAppInfo.getPackage(SourceFile:226)
   at com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol$1.run(SourceFile:763)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

my code

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                     Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {

            });

    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                }
            });
```

why this error coming its not always coming , and any way we have extra step if we are using porductflaovers in android

Comment: Not sure what you expect as an answer. None of this stack trace is your code. You should file a bug report to the Facebook developers

Comment: What code of yours is calling whatever function causes this exception to be thrown? This looks like a problem with the underlying implementation, but perhaps you're using the API incorrectly? More context would go a long way to helping us help you.

Comment: @cricket_007 check my edited us